# vagrant provisioned virtualbox cannot access the internet when booted up with an active VPN connection on the windows 7 host

Tags: windows, ubuntu, vagrant, virtualbox, vpn

I have a problem with networking while setting up a development virtual machine

The host environment is:

- Windows 7x64
- Vagrant 1.7.2
- Virtualbox 4.3.20 r96997
- has an active WLAN internet connections
- can connect to a VPN

The relevant sections from the `Vagrantfile` are:

```
ENV['VAGRANT_DEFAULT_PROVIDER'] = 'virtualbox'
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
  config.vm.define 'crm' do |node|
    node.vm.network :private_network, ip: '192.168.56.2'
  end
end
```

With this, the guest machine has two network interfaces:

- `eth0`: NAT
- `eth1`: the private network

After a `vagrant up` the machine is always accessible through the private IP.
However, if at boot time the VPN connection

- is active, then the guest machine cannot access the internet
- is not active, then the guest machine can access the internet

On the host machine, with an active VPN connection, both public and VPN-restricted hosts are accessible.

**Question**: how should I modify the Vagrantfile to ensure that the guest machine always has internet access, regardless whether it was booted with an active VPN connection on the host machine or not?

**Update**:
adding

```
config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--natdnshostresolver1", "on"]
end
```

solves the internet connectivity issue, however, it brings the boot time of the guest machine to barely tolerable (many minutes)

Answer (score 2):

ok. i had the same problem but i am using windows. i did fix it. what i did is that opened virtualbox.

1. go to settings
2. select network
3. change second adapter
4. select under " attached to: " ' Host-only Adapter'
5. under name. i selected " virtualbox host-only ethernet apdapter " do not select the name that have numbers at the end of the name example : #1, #2 and so on.
6. i went to my device manager and delete all the virtual network drivers "not your physical network drivers". again this was in windows 8.
7. i restart my pc
8. confirm my chance have applied
9. i vagrant up on my project directory and it was working